# C# multi-coloured text in a single cell of a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, colors

Is it possible to change the colour of a sub string present in a datagridview cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [CellPainting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz.aspx) event to customize how the cell is drawn.