# Change specific word color in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm creating a `WinForms` application that represents some data to the user. In my data, I want to highlight some words with specific colors. I can do this in an `ASP.NET` application by adding a style sheet and use it in my grid-view like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254582/change-forecolor-af-a-special-word-in-gridview-cell).
How can I achieve the same result in a `WinForms gridview`?

I'm using the code below but it changes the color for the whole cell, I want to change only the color of the word.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                foreach( string word in wordss)
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(word.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [CellPainting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz.aspx) event to customize how the cell is drawn. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107772/c-sharp-multi-coloured-text-in-a-single-cell-of-a-datagridview), hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [`DataBindingComplete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event for processing each row. To change color of a particular cell you can use `System.Drawing.Color` class. Hope that helps you yo get going.

Check MSDN for more information on the same.

Comment: I tried to make your solution but this change the cell i want only change specific word

Comment: @AhmedZainy, that logic you will have to include and check each cells value to match for the specific word. If match found then change color of that cell.

Comment: `private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    foreach( string word in wordss)
                        if (cell.Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(word.ToUpper()))
                        {
                            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,      
 DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e){
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

           foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
              {

             foreach( string word in wordss)

              if (cell.Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(word.ToUpper()))
                {
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you add for the  code in my question ?! it is the same code

Comment: @Osama, besides the fact that the code in your answer is the same as the code in the question, you need at least to explain in a few words why/how to use it.

Comment: You should comment a little about why exactly you posted like this.